Woocommerce GraphQL and Rest API with next js takes too long to Update
I am using woocommerce graph ql to query products on my Next JS frontend. The issue is that sometimes when I update a product on the wordpress dashboard, it takes time to update on the frontend (around 2minute to 10 minute) or unless I refresh. How can I make this faster and automatic. Wordpress site is on Hostinger and Frontend is on Vercel
Version 1.3.8 | By WPGraphQL
Version 0.8.1 | WPGraphQL WooCommerce (WooGraphQL)

import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  createHttpLink,
} from "@apollo/client";

/**
 * Middleware operation
 * If we have a session token in localStorage, add it to the GraphQL request as a Session header.
 */
export const middleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  /**
   * If session data exist in local storage, set value as session header.
   */
  const session = process.browser
    ? localStorage.getItem("my-app-session")
    : null;

  if (session) {
    operation.setContext(() => ({
      headers: {
        "woocommerce-session": `Session ${session}`,
      },
    }));
  }

  return forward(operation);
});

/**
 * Afterware operation.
 *
 * This catches the incoming session token and stores it in localStorage, for future GraphQL requests.
 */
export const afterware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return forward(operation).map((response) => {
    if (!process.browser) {
      return response;
    }

    /**
     * Check for session header and update session in local storage accordingly.
     */
    const context = operation.getContext();
    const {
      response: { headers },
    } = context;
    const session = headers.get("woocommerce-session");

    if (session) {
      // Remove session data if session destroyed.
      if ("false" === session) {
        localStorage.removeItem("my-app-session");

        // Update session new data if changed.
      } else if (localStorage.getItem("my-app-sessionn") !== session) {
        localStorage.setItem(
          "moutai-session",
          headers.get("woocommerce-session")
        );
      }
    }

    return response;
  });
});

// Apollo GraphQL client.
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: middleware.concat(
    afterware.concat(
      createHttpLink({
        uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_URL}/graphql`,
        fetch,
        credentials: "include",
      })
    )
  ),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
}); 

export default client;

collections/index.tsx
import { CollectionLists } from "@/components/sections/CollectionLists";
import { Product } from "@/actions";
import client from "@/ApolloClient";
import PRODUCTS_AND_CATEGORIES_QUERY from "@/queries/product-and-categories";

export default function AllCollections({ products }: { products: Product[] }) {
  return (
    <section className="mx-auto flex flex-col  uppercase bg-accent-600 lg:pt-32 pt-20">
      <CollectionHeader title={"Shop"} desc={"Store Description"} />
      <CollectionLists
        backgroundColorClass={"bg-accent-1000"}
        products={products}
        slug={"Products"}
      />
    </section>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: PRODUCTS_AND_CATEGORIES_QUERY,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      products: data?.products?.nodes ? data.products.nodes : [],
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}```


Tried Clearing local storage immediately I added product and setting revalidate to 1. Still no progress

